# Regex for number of different characters

Tags: regex

Let's say I want a regex to match whenever a string has less than `k` different characters.  That is, if `k=2`, it would match `aaaa` or `a` but not match `abc`.  Can regex do this, and if so, can I pass in a variable `k` to the match expression?

Comment: What do you mean by _types of characters_? Do you mean `k` different characters?

Comment: You might be able to do this with negative lookarounds, but I you would have to tailor the regexp for each value of `k`. This seems like something that would be much easier to do with string-processing code than a regexp.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, thats what i mean

Comment: So are you trying to match a string that is comprised only of the letter a, or whatever character value is in variable a, and has k number of characters or less, but at least 1? If so, then this would work, assuming you're doing this in a programming language where the substitution would occur: `a{1,k}$`

Comment: I don't know of any way to do what you're trying to do with regex.  If I were you I'd just use regex to get the characters of the type you want and split the string into individual characters, sort them, unique-ify them, and test the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but it will require you to construct the regular expression and not just substituting a number in the regex and be done with it.

Instead of searching for strings with less than or equal to `k` distinct characters, let us search for strings with strictly more than `k` distinct characters.

For `k` = 1:

```
^(.).*?((?!\1).)
```

This will match any string with 2 or more distinct characters (i.e. strictly more than 1 character).

For `k` = 2:

```
^(.).*?((?!\1).).*?((?!\1|\2).)
```

Same as above, this will match any string with 3 or more distinct characters.

We can extend this to higher `k`, by adding more `.*?((?!...).)` to the end, where the pattern inside the negative look-ahead will check against an alternation of all the characters that have been captured in the preceding capturing groups.

Back to the original problem, we only need to place the pattern after `^` inside a negative look-ahead to negate what it matches.

As an example for `k` = 2:

```
^(?!(.).*?((?!\1).).*?((?!\1|\2).))
```

The pattern above will only return a match (of an empty string, since the beginning of string `^` and the negative look-ahead are zero-width) iff the string has `k` or less distinct characters.

Note that there is a caveat to this method. Since the number of capturing groups and back-references increases with `k`, it may exceed the limit of number of capturing groups allowed in a pattern.

The regex is also inefficient at higher `k`, where the worst case is a string with `k` distinct characters. One way is to change the construction to restrict the `.*?` part to match only characters captured in the previous capturing groups.

```
^(?!(.)(?:\1)*((?!\1).)(?:\1|\2)*((?!\1|\2).))
```